# I have a json coming from a rest service which I want to convert into C# object

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, restsharp

my Json:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-03 14:46:00",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2017-08-03 14:46:00": {
        "1. open": "157.0500",
        "2. high": "157.2100",
        "3. low": "155.2800",
        "4. close": "155.6400",
        "5. volume": "17218406"
    },
    "2017-08-02": {
        "1. open": "159.2800",
        "2. high": "159.7500",
        "3. low": "156.1600",
        "4. close": "157.1400",
        "5. volume": "69222793"
    },
  }
}
```

my class:

```
  public class myDataType{
        public class inf
        {
            public string Information { get; set; }
            public string Symbol { get; set; }
            public string Last_Refreshed { get; set; }
            public string Output_Size { get; set; }
            public string Time_Zone { get; set; }
        }
        public class stock
        {
            public string open { get; set; }
            public string high { get; set; }
            public string low { get; set; }
            public string close { get; set; }
            public string volume { get; set; }
        }
        public class StockLists
        {
            public stock[] stock;
        }
        public inf information { get; set; }
        public StockLists Stocklist { get; set; }
        //public IList<stock> stocks { get; set; }


    }
```

my Questions:

- Is my class Interpretation right/ wrong/ can be improved?
- How to convert this json to object of class myDataType?

I've tried to desearalize  the object using the method given in this link [Deserialize an Object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) but it is giving me an error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type \u0027Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject\u0027 to \u0027Scrapper.Controllers.HomeController.dataType\u0027

any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: we can't really tell the error if we don't have the code that attempt to do the deserialization

Comment: Also, the number prefix (like "1. ") might break your deserialization

Comment: Your JSON key names are all invalid. No Spaces allowed. If you want for it to automatically deserialize you need to have same key names and property names. `"firstName": "John"` would be `public string firstName;`.

Comment: @Spectarion The spec only says the name of the key must be a string http://www.json.org/

Comment: @Spectarion Thank You.